# Smarty create grid/table structure with CSS, without extra HTML

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I have a basic `<ul>` list in HTML that I would like to convert into a 3 column grid. each list item has a fixed width  floated left, so ideally I would like:

```
<ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
    <li class="clear">List 4</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
    <li>List 6</li>
    <li class="clear">List 7</li>
    <li>List 8</li>
    <li>List 9</li>
    <li class="clear">List 10</li>
</ul>
```

At the moment I have tried this:

```
<ul>
{foreach $submenu.child.items as $row} 
    <li class="{if $row@iteration is div by 4}clear{/if}"><a href="#">{$row.label}</a></li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

As you can see below this works apart from the first row. E.G:

```
<ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
    <li class="clear">List 4</li>
    <li>List 5</li>
    <li>List 6</li>
    <li>List 7</li>
    <li class="clear">List 8</li>
    <li>List 9</li>
    <li>List 10</li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE:
The only way I can get this to work is by adding extra HTML. Is there any other way?

```
<ul>
{foreach $submenu.child.items as $row} 
    <li><a href="">{$row.label}</a></li>
    {if $row@iteration % 3 == 0}<li class="clearBoth"></li>{/if}
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Comment: What works? What happens? What doesn't happen in IE? What are you expecting?

Comment: You can see what works from the HTML output I have pasted, this shows what happens. I am expecting it to work like the first example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you care whether the first entry has "clear"?

If you don't, then

```
 {if $row@iteration % 3 == 1}
```

If you do, then you'll need

```
 {if $row@iteration > 1 && $row@iteration % 3 == 1}
```

(or whatever the syntax is in Smarty).

It would have been more helpful if you had explained the problem, i.e. that it was about counting, not anything to do with HTML or Smarty.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you. I can't believe how long I spent trying to figure this out and I was so close with the "0"

Comment: Also I will try to rephrase the question in future. I just wanted to give as much examples so you understood what I was trying to do.

Comment: I appreciate that you were trying to, but examples are not helpful if you don't know what you're looking for in them! Your reference to IE made me think that this was a problem about CSS or subtle HTML, that worked in some browsers and didn't work in others.